# Can I build a settlement on a "broken" road?

Tags: catan

If I have a settlement with many roads connected, let’s say at least 6 roads deep, and my opponent cuts it off and builds a settlement between them, can I still build a settlement at the deep end even though my roads aren’t connected to my settlement anymore?

Answer (score 16):

## yes

From the [rules](https://www.catan.com/sites/prod/files/2021-06/catan_base_rules_2020_200707.pdf):

> - You may only build a settlement at an intersection if all 3 of the
>   adjacent intersections are vacant.
> - Each of your settles must connect to at least one of your roads.

If you don't break either of those rules and you have the resources you may build a settlement.

You might be getting confused with how a player 'breaking' a road with their settlement can shorten the longest road. Another player building a settlement on your road doesn't prevent you building a settlement if it is not adjacent to where you want to build.